# Let $R$ be a PID and $I$ a prime ideal of $R$ s.t. $0 \subset I \subset 1_R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, principal-ideal-domains, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $R$ be a PID and $I$ a prime ideal of $R$ s.t. $0 \subset I \subset 1_R$ and let $I = \langle a \rangle$, where $a$ is a prime element of $R$.

My question is: is there any other prime ideal $J$ s.t. $0\subset J \subset I$?

Here is all I know: $a$ is prime and irreducible element in $R$ and $I$ is a maximal ideal of $R$. Also, I think the answer would be no(since $I$ is a prime ideal). But, then again I am not sure. Could anyone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Let me get this clear. Then, $J$ can't be the maximal ideal since $0\subset J \subset I \subset R$, can it?

Comment: In a PID every prime ideal is either $0$ or maximal.

Comment: @Jellyfish Through like 6 edits I've finally made it reasonable I believe. What you ask for follows.

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand the concept.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $0\subset J\subseteq I\subseteq R$ with $J$ prime. Since all ideals are principal, we have $J=(a)$ and $I=(b)$ for a prime $a$ and some $b\in R$.
Since $I\supseteq J$ we have $a=bd$ for some $d\in R$. Since $a$ is prime we have $a\mid d$ or $a\mid b$.

If $a\mid d$ then $a=abe$ for some $e\in R$. Since every PID is an integral domain, we have $1=be$, and $I=R$. If $a\mid b$, then $b=ae$  for some $e\in R$. Let $x\in I$. Then $x=cb$ for some $c\in R$ and, by substituting the above, $x=cea$ so $J\subseteq I \subseteq J$ and $I=J$.

---

Note this shows every prime ideal, not $0$, is maximal. It follows that no nonzero prime ideal contains another nonzero prime ideal.

Comment: @user26857 I believe I have fixed the problem.

Comment: I use $(a)$ to mean the ideal generated by $a$. It is the same as $\langle a \rangle$ but easier to type and I believe follows the notation of Dedekind.

Comment: is that the same $a$ of $I$ that you chose for $J$.  If so, why? Is this b/c every ideal is a principle in a P.I.D, and does that mean they can have the same generator?

Comment: @Jellyfish I'm not sure what the question is. Every ideal in a PID is principal however.

Comment: You wrote $J = (a)$. But, $I = (a)$ from the question. I was asking are these the same $a$?

Comment: @jellyfish oops. I switched them in my response. It doesn't change the meaning as the response is self-contained.

Comment: Ok, so we can write it like this: we have $I = (a)$ and $J = (b)$, for some primes $a,b \in R$, right?

Comment: @jellyfish only one needs to be prime.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ $ For principal ideals: $\,\ \rm\color{#0a0}{contains} = \color{#c00}{divides},\,$ i.e.  $\,(a)\supset (b)\iff a\mid b,\,$ hence

$$\begin{align} (p)\text{ is prime}\ \Rightarrow&\,\ \ p\ \text{ is prime}\\
\Rightarrow&\,\ \ p\ \text{ is irreducible}\\
\Rightarrow&\ \ \,p\ \ \text{ has no proper}\,\ {\rm\color{#c00}{divisor}}\,\ a\\
\Rightarrow&\ (p)\, \text{ has no proper } \,{\rm\color{#0a0}{container}}\,\ (a)\\
\Rightarrow&\ (p)\, \text{ is maximal}
\end{align}\qquad$$